# AWS: Inbound rules configured to a security group not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache, aws-security-group

I've an elasticache service with an inbound rule configured to a common security group: cache-services-SG. I've configured the inbound rule of cache-SG to include the SG of the services. When I telnet from the service instances, I am unable to connect to the elasticache service. However, when I directly add the SG of service to inbound rules of elasticache ClusterSG, it works. May I know what could be happening?

Heirarchy of the SG:

```
a. ClusterSG
   cache-services-SG

b. cache-services-SG
   - service A - port: x
   - service B - port: x
```

I've reviewed this post but I am not sure if I can access the private dns of the elasticache.
https://serverfault.com/questions/855817/aws-inbound-rules-not-working-for-security-group

Comment: If you have enabled [VPC Flow Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/), then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which AWS resource is rejecting the network traffic.

Comment: I've checked the vpc logs as you suggested. I see the eni of cluster is rejecting the service ip address. I also confirm that the service is part of the common SG.